# Texture appearing in squares across the map

Tags: texturing

I was following a tutorial on how to paint textures on to a object and for some reason, when I started painting, the texture didn't show up in its proper place. It just appeared in squares all around the map. if anyone has a solution to this, Please let me know.

[image: Here is an image simplifying everything.]

[image]

Comment: You need to unwrap the mesh again, currently the mesh unwrapped in small square UV islands, thats why you are getting this result.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at your UV map. If you try using the color grid or UV preset textures (when you create a new texture) you should be able to see if your UV map makes sense, or if it's causing the issue.

If the UV map is the problem, you can probably just UV unwrap your object again. To make a flat UV map from above your object (which should work for your terrain), switch to edit mode with Tab, toggle to orthographic view with Ctrl+5, switch to top view with Ctrl+7,  then select UV unwrap (or press U) > Project from View (Bounds).

Comment: I did exactly what you told me to do about the UV map and it didn't do anything, do you maybe have any other solution

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong then. Your texture is definitely on the map, and you can see faces that have portions of your texture applied.

Comment: I've added a picture of them both in edit mode and this is what its showing me

Comment: I figured it out thanks for your help anyway

Comment: make sure there are no overlapping island in your UV map. try smart projection